# Chrome eats all RAM and freezes system

Tags: linux, arch-linux, chrome, ram

How to prevent chrome to take more than for example 4GB of ram. From time to time he decides to take something like 7GB (with 8GB RAM total) and makes my computer unusable.

Do you have any help.

PS: I even didn't have more than 10 tabs opened.
Edit: maybe I did ... something like 15. Anyway I want chrome to freeze or shutdown not to freeze the whole system.

Comment: Have you looked into `limits.conf` or `ulimit`?

Comment: That's a wonderful idea! Too bad `ulimit` is unsupported for [Windows](https://serverfault.com/q/197241/85654)!

Comment: I have few (React dev, plugin, Vimium, Addblock, few google plugins) So I don't excpect those to eat like 4GB of RAM

Comment: My Solution was buy more memory, now have 32GB , no issues anymore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you would want to use something like `cgroups` to limit resource usage for a individual process.

So you might want to do something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510913/how-to-set-a-memory-limit-for-a-specific-process#510936) except with

`cgcreate -g memory,cpu:chromegroup
cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes=2048 chromegroup`

to create chromegroup and restrict the memory usage for the group to 2048 bytes

`cgclassify -g memory,cpu:chromegroup $(pidof chrome)`

to move the current chrome processes into the group and restrict their memory usage to the set limit

or just launch chrome within the group like

`cgexec -g memory,cpu:chromegroup chrome`

However, it's pretty insane that chrome is using that much memory in the first place. Try purging reinstalling / recompiling first to see if that doesn't fix the issue, because it really should not be using that much memory to begin with, and this solution is only a band-aid over the real problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with Firefox, even though it works fine on another RAM-constrained system, with far less available to it. I think browser developers have decided they should use to all RAM available, on any system.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can use the **ulimit** utility.
The **-d** option:
[ulimit(3) man page](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)

You can lower your soft limit even without **root** access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to improve Chrome's behavior is to simply configure the JavaScript heap limits. Add this to the command line when starting Chrome:

`--js-flags="--max_old_space_size=80 --max_semi_space_size=80"`

This tells the JavaScript GC to limit memory usage to under 160M
Of course you can change the numbers for your specific situation.